# Можно ли сделать уникальный ключ в MySQL с несколькими столбцами, один из которых может быть нулевым?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key

Например, в таблице есть три столбца integer..

Эти строки: 1-1-1 и 1-1-1 - не являются уникальными, по этому если есть первая, вторую создать никак..  
 А эти строки: 1-NULL-1 и 1-NULL-1, хоть и "не являются уникальными", всё равно можно создавать...

Как создать unique ключ, чтобы строки 1-NULL-1 и 1-NULL-1 всё-таки перестали быть уникальными?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим, что nullable поле называется `X`.

Создайте новое виртуальное вычисляемое поле того же типа (назовем его `X_non_null`) в таблице базируясь на значении из `X`. Если значение `NULL`, то в `X_non_null` устанавливайте не NULL значение, которое точно не встретится в `X`, т.е определение такого поля будет:

```
X_non_null INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (IFNULL(X, -1))
```

И теперь создавайте уникальное ограничение используя `X_non_null` вместо `X`.

Спасибо [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) за подсказку этой относительно новой возможности в mysql. В версиях до 5.7 и других БД, где нет вычисляемых полей, это можно делать тригеррами.

Comment: Дополнительное поле, обновляемое триггером - плохое решение, особенно если вспомнить, что триггеры не работают каскадно. Гораздо проще и разумнее организовать то же самое, но используя вычисляемое поле (generated column). Тем более что оно может быть и виртуальным - тогда его добавление не приведёт к росту объёма таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо. Согласен, вычисляемое виртуальное поле лучше.

Comment: @Akina у вас есть ссылочка, где описано, как реализовать это?

Comment: @JackThursby прочитайте ответ выше ;)